# get vs filter_by in data query for composite primary key table

Tags: mysql, rest, sqlalchemy

**Question in Short:**

What is the difference between query.get() and query.filter_by() when trying to get data according to multiple primary keys(columns)? (is there a speed factor, efficiency, etc) and can query.get be used by mentioning only few of the primary keys as well(Say, I know 2 of the 4 multiple keys)???

**Question in Detail:**

I am working on writing Rest APIs for a database which has tables with a composite primary key table(multiple primary key columns) in SQLAlchemy. Say my table contains the primary key columns as : State, City and I want to write the get query using their primary keys. I found that I can write it as one of the below two:

```
query(TableName).get_or_404(('StateName', 'CityName'))
query(TableName).filter_by(State = 'StateName', City = 'CityName')
```

Both work fine in case I know both the primary keys. But in case I know only one primary key, I can only make it work through the 'filter_by' (adding .all() next to it) but not 'get' as it gives insufficient arguments error. So, what is the best way to implement the query over primary keys in case of composite type? or is there any mistake in the way I tried implementing them.

Also as a follow up question can some one tell me if implementing the URI for multiple(3 or 4) primary key get queries, the usage: ....site_path/<State>/<City> a good practice or not?

Comment: If you set `echo=True` on the engine, do `.get` and `.filter_by` generate different SQL?

Comment: `Query.get` can fetch the object from the identity map, if it has been loaded in the session before. A filtered query has to perform a fetch from the database.

Comment: Thanks.. but what about using Query.get when only few of the primary keys are know? is it possible to use it any differently? @IljaEverilä